# QGIS - Python - QGIS freeze but still running

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

Is there anyway to not let QGIS freeze everytime I try to run python progress script.

Even the script below would freeze at 50%...

```
import time
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QProgressBar
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
progressMessageBar = iface.messageBar().createMessage("Doing something boring...")
progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setMaximum(10)
progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(progress)
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(progressMessageBar, Qgis.Info)

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    progress.setValue(i + 1)
iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
```

I expecting to see the messageBar to reach 100%

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to guarantee that your main Qt thread will not freese because of your script. QGIS already has an API for this case named the task manager. Take a look [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html). I have adapted your sample to this API. Running this script will create standard progress background task progress bar. You can found information about creating more flexible tasks in documentation.

```
import time

from qgis.core import (
  QgsProcessingContext,
  QgsTaskManager,
  QgsTask,
  QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask,
  Qgis,
  QgsProcessingFeedback,
  QgsApplication,
  QgsMessageLog,
)

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'TaskFromFunction'

def heavyFunction(task):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Started task {}'.format(task.description()),
                             MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        task.setProgress(i)
        # without folowwing statement your task will be unstoppable
        if task.isCanceled():
            return None
    pass

def workdone():
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("DONE", MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
    pass

task = QgsTask.fromFunction('heavy function', heavyFunction,
                     on_finished=workdone)

QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
```

This solution might not be suitable for your particular use case because you can't call any main's thread QObject from background. I haven't found direct answer on your question about `QProgressBar` message bar. However there is a useful case [with progress bar in dialog box](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381822/showing-dialog-box-even-though-qgis-is-freezing). [Also, this answer about QProgressbar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432797/pyqt-progress-bar-freezing) doesn't work for me. I can quess that this freezing is just standard behavior of main Qt thread when you try to make some hard computations in it.

Anyway, most of GUI elements in main thread won't be usable during some hard computations wich make this approach not user-friendly at all. I would advise you to take a closer look at background tasks.